# linq statement return duplicate record

Tags: linq

I would like to translate the linq statement from using 
    select * from dbo.vwListDetails where productid ='20D9F725-6667-4F3A-893A-7D30FED550BE'

I have write the linq statement however it return incorrect data

using the sql statment above it return:

```
productid                            productname custmerid customername 
20D9F725-6667-4F3A-893A-7D30FED550BE         nike         1        andy
20D9F725-6667-4F3A-893A-7D30FED550BE         nike         2        randy  

public IEnumerable<vwListDetails > GetAllListDetailConsumer(Guid productid)
{
    ObjectQuery<vwListDetails> cust = db.vwListDetails ;
    IEnumerable<vwListDetails> query = from d in cust 
                                       where d.productid == productid
                                       select d;
    return query;

}
```

if i use the linq c# code above it return

```
  productid                                  productname custmerid customer name 
  20D9F725-6667-4F3A-893A-7D30FED550BE         nike         1        andy
  20D9F725-6667-4F3A-893A-7D30FED550BE         nike         1        andy
```

Comment: It really won't. I suspect you've got a bug somewhere else. (As an aside, I'd write your entire method body as `return db.vwListDetails.Where(d => d.productid == new Guid(productid));` - or possibly construct the `Guid` in one statement and then use it in a similar one.

Comment: Why do you use that condition: `d.productid == new Guid(productid)`? That's really weird.

Comment: Your question is currently misleading, as your example uses `20` as a product ID, whereas your C# code uses a GUID. Which is it?

Comment: Check the primary key of the view in the EF model. I bet it's not a unique key. (Assuming this is entity framework).

Comment: My apology, i have update the code. thx

Comment: Yes, it is Entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` condition is incorrect. I think you need that one:

```
public IEnumerable<vwListDetails > GetAllListDetailConsumer(string productid)
{
    ObjectQuery<vwListDetails> cust = db.vwListDetails ;
    IEnumerable<vwListDetails> query = from d in cust 
                                       where d.productid == productid
                                       select d;
    return query;
}
```

Comment: If it's returning results at all, I don't think it's wrong. I suspect the original example was simply misleading.

Answer (score -1):

i suspect your condition is wrong. your producid will never match the GUID.

1. You are doing wrong with predicate.   `where d.productid == new Guid(productid)`.
2. As you said in the Example of Sql. you are mentioning the productid. but using LINQ you are using GUID. so correct the predicate.

   `var urList=  db.vwListDetails.Select(e=>e.productid==yourCondition);`

Comment: The data is already distinct. LINQ just won't behave the way that has been described with the queries shown - the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @JonSkeet i mentioned that also. for the predicate is wrong .

Comment: But `Distinct()` is a complete red-herring, and we don't really *know* that the predicate is wrong. It's bad with the example of "20" in the SQL query, but it's entirely possible that a GUID is being read as a string from a text file, and that the productid property really is a GUID.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok :) i will remove DIstinct().  i misunderstood the question. I edited answer to meet his requirement.